# Google Analytics PHP API: Get event total events

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api

The analytics api allows you get events and total events across the profile, but I can't work out how to get the total events of a particular event. For example:

1. Event 1 has 10 total events and 3
   unique events.
2. Event 2 has 5 total events and 5
   unique events.

If I use `ga:totalEvents`, it will return 15 and `ga:uniqueEvents` will return 8. How can I filter it down to category (ie title... Event 1, Event 2 are "Categories").

[Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html#ga%3atotalEvents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `ga:eventAction` and/or `ga:eventCategory` dimensions to the request. This will give you a breakdown of the `ga:totalEvents` and `ga:uniqueEvents` metrics for each action and category.

Comment: I already have the eventAction and eventCategory dimensions included, can you expand a little please?